# displaying web pages over web views in collection view using cocoa bindings

Tags: cocoa, webview, cocoa-bindings, nscollectionview

I tried sample example given at this link - [Collection View Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CollectionViews/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009030)

It is simple and it worked. Considering it as a reference I tried a simple application which will show a collection view of web views with some web page displayed over each web view.

The model class has two properties: NSString *pageName, and NSURL *pageURL.

I then followed each and every step written in tutorial above with required modifications but I was caught in the step -

> How to bind web view to collection
>   view item?

In binding tab it shows three possibilities : Editable, Hidden, Tool tip but none of these is working.

Can anyone suggest me way to accomplish my requirement?

Thanks,

Miraaj

Comment: ok ... thanks for your valuable suggestion :)

Answer (score 1):

WebView does not expose bindings for the URL (one would think it would, but it doesn't). You'll need to make use of [NSCollectionViewItem](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSCollectionViewItem_Class/Introduction/Introduction.html) (create a custom subclass) and update your WebView's URL when its represented object is changed.

The quick start guide you referenced does not show how to use a custom collection view item (it shows a very basic case). You'll need to delve a little deeper into the documentation (and online [examples](http://andrehoffmann.wordpress.com/2009/08/29/nscollectionview-tutorial-for-dummies-xcode-3-1-3/)) to achieve your goal.

I would offer one thought to consider regarding your overall goal: WebView is a "heavy" object, so keep your performance expectations realistic regarding creating many of these views.

Comment: ok.. I want to get the safari new window like feature where they show collection of web pages and when a user clicks any of the sub-views , it opens that link!